# How to set iframe src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Does anybody could explain me how to change/set src attribute in iframe by javascript?
I use `document.getElementById().innerHTML` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

do:

```
document.getElementById('your_iframe_id').src = "some_location";
```

innerHTML gives you the inner html content not iframe's src attribute